# Converting a query url to a json

Tags: javascript, json, api, url, search

This is the first time Im asking a question on Stackoverflow, so i excuse in advance if its not properly formulated 
I'll keep it it short and simple. I want to convert what i get from this url: 

 http://hotell.difi.no/api/json/brreg/enhetsregisteret?query=company
to a JSON or array in JavaScript, how do i do this?. 
This is going to be a part of a search-webapplication where I just change the query parameter when the user changes the input.

 
I must admit that I'm completely new at this, and I don't even know if I'm asking the question correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make a string into a json object, simply use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```
var obj = JSON.parse(string);
```

You can use [`jQuery.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) if you are using Ajax and you don't mind [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

```
var obj = $.getJSON( "http://hotell.difi.no/api/json/brreg/enhetsregisteret?query=company", function() {
  console.log( "DONE" );
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Keyword "urlparse javascript"

#### Node server

[`url.parse()`](http://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_parse_urlstr_parsequerystring_slashesdenotehost)

#### Client

This (creating an `<a>` DOM object) is quick and dirty, but it works:
https://gist.github.com/jlong/2428561

**Do** use more stable library such as [parseuri](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/parseuri) and [URI.js](http://medialize.github.io/URI.js/) for this task.